# How do I print a query by MySQL's version in sql file?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to print query by MySQL's version in .sql file.

When I use MySQL version 5.6, want to print (2 column)

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

or, I use MySQL version 5.7 or 8, want to print (3 column)

```
SELECT user, host, account_locked FROM mysql.user;
```

Because MySQL 5.6 version doesn't have account_locked column.

Comment: You need to maintain versions of your code compatible with the DDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'version';
+---------------+-----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE  |
+---------------+-----------------+
| VERSION       | 5.6.22-71.0-log |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| version       | 5.6.22-71.0-log |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.22-71.0-log |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In a Stored Procedure, you can do something like

```
IF (@@version < "5.7") THEN
    SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
ELSE
    SELECT user, host, account_locked FROM mysql.user;
ENDIF;
```

It gets messier if you also need to handle MariaDB, with its "10.x.y".  And, if Percona has any differences, you need to dig deeper into the "version".